# Why does the local storage get deleted when I refresh?

Tags: javascript, next.js, local-storage

In Next.js I'm using this code:

```
  const [card, setcard] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(card));
  }, [card]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items'));
    if (items) {
      setcard(items);
    }
  }, []);
```

I can see that when the value of the card changes, the local storage shows me the value of the card, which is a JSON, so when I refresh, I just see this `[]`

I used this tutorial: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-localstorage-with-react-hooks-to-set-and-get-items/

How can I fix the code so I don't lose the value of the card after a refresh?

Also, I was using `cookies` to store the `card` like this, and it was working, but when the items in my JSON got larger, the cookie didn't store anymore; that's why I want to use local storage.

Example:

```
  const [card, setcard] = useState(() => eval(getCookie('card') || []));
  setCookie('card', JSON.stringify(card), {
    path: '/',
    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24,
    HttpOnly: true,
    Secure: true,
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your first `useEffect` (with the dependency array `[card]`) gets triggered before your `useEffect` hook without any dependency array. You could probably fix it by reversing the order of them, but I would be more thorough than that and only have the one with the `[card]` dependency array do the save if it sees something other than the default `[]` that you're supplying. Here's a way to do that:

```
// Outside the component
const defaultCard = [];

function YourComponent() {
    const [card, setCard] = useState(defaultCard);

    useEffect(() => {
        const items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("items"));
        if (items) {
            setCard(items);
        }
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (card !== defaultCard) { // Note we're checking *object identity* here
            localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(card));
        }
    }, [card]);
    
    // ...
}
```

Using object identity makes it so that the code will never save the *specific* empty array we used as a default (but **will** store an empty array resulting from the user removing all the cards on purpose).

Alternatively, don't rely on an effect to save the array. Instead, have a wrapper for `setCard`:

```
function YourComponent() {
    const [card, setCardWorker] = useState(defaultCard);

    const setCard = useCallback(
        (card) => {
            localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(card));
            setCardWorker(card);
        },
        [setCardWorker]
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        const items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("items"));
        if (items) {
            setCard(items);
        }
    }, []);
    
    // ...code using `setCard` to update `card` as things are added and removed...
}
```

*(I've used `setCard` rather than `setcard` in these because the vastly common standard is to capitalize the noun after `set` in these things rather than use all lower-case.*

Answer (score 1):

When your page reloads, the cards are set to `[]` and the `useEffect` hook gets called so local storage's `items` is set to `[]`.

You need to check whether card has length or not and then set.

```
const [card, setcard] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (card.length) {
    localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(card));
  }
}, [card]);

useEffect(() => {
  const items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items'));
  if (items) {
    setcard(items);
  }
}, []);
```

Comment: Thank you for adding some explanation (your first version was just a code dump, which isn't useful). But this will never save an empty array, even if the user intentionally removed all elements from it. You need to differentiate between the empty array used as an initializer and just *an* empty array.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that your initial `card` value is `[]`, regardless of the contents of `items` in `localStorage`.

Instead of using `[]`, you should first check `localStorage`. If there there is no value for `items`, use your default `[]`. However if there is a value present, use that as initial value instead.

```js
const [card, setcard] = useState(() => {
  const json = localStorage.getItem('items');
  if (!json) return []; // default card
  return JSON.parse(json);
});

useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(card));
}, [card]);
```